# How can I improve this Clojure Component+async example?

Tags: clojure, components, core.async

I want to figure out how best to create an async component, or accommodate async code in a Component-friendly way. This is the best I can come up with, and... it just doesn't feel quite right.

**The Gist**: take words, `uppercase` them and `reverse` them, finally `print` them.

**Problem 1**: I can't get the `system` to stop at the end. I expect to see a `println` of the individual `c-chan`s stopping, but don't.

**Problem 2**: How do I properly inject deps. into the `producer`/`consumer` fns? I mean, they're not components, and I think they should *not* be components since they have no sensible lifecycle.

**Problem 3**: How do I idiomatically handle the `async/pipeline`-creating side-effects named `a>b`, and `b>c`? Should a `pipeline` be a component?

```
(ns pipelines.core
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as async
             :refer [go >! <! chan pipeline-blocking close!]]
            [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]))


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; PIPELINES
(defn a>b [a> b>]
  (pipeline-blocking 4
                     b>
                     (map clojure.string/upper-case)
                     a>))
(defn b>c [b> c>]
  (pipeline-blocking 4
                     c>
                     (map (comp (partial apply str)
                                reverse))
                     b>))


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; PRODUCER / CONSUMER
(defn producer [a>]
  (doseq [word ["apple" "banana" "carrot"]]
    (go (>! a> word))))

(defn consumer [c>]
  (go (while true
        (println "Your Word Is: " (<! c>)))))



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; SYSTEM
(defn pipeline-system [config-options]
  (let [c-chan (reify component/Lifecycle
                 (start [this]
                   (println "starting chan: " this)
                   (chan 1))
                 (stop [this]
                   (println "stopping chan: " this)
                   (close! this)))]
    (-> (component/system-map
         :a> c-chan
         :b> c-chan
         :c> c-chan)
        (component/using {}))))


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; RUN IT!
(def system (atom nil))
(let [_      (reset! system (component/start (pipeline-system {})))
      _      (a>b (:a> @system) (:b> @system))
      _      (b>c (:b> @system) (:c> @system))
      _      (producer (:a> @system))
      _      (consumer (:c> @system))
      _      (component/stop @system)])
```

---

**EDIT**:

I started thinking about the following, but I'm not quite sure if it's closing properly...

```
(extend-protocol component/Lifecycle
  clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel
  (start [this]
    this)
  (stop [this]
    (close! this)))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I rewrote your example a little to make it *reloadable*:

## Reloadable Pipeline

```
(ns pipeline
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as ca :refer [>! <!]]
            [clojure.string :as s]))

(defn upverse [from to]
  (ca/pipeline-blocking 4
                        to
                        (map (comp s/upper-case
                                   s/reverse))
                        from))
(defn produce [ch xs]
  (doseq [word xs]
    (ca/go (>! ch word))))

(defn consume [ch]
  (ca/go-loop []
              (when-let [word (<! ch)]
                (println "your word is:" word)
                (recur))))

(defn start-engine []
  (let [[from to] [(ca/chan) (ca/chan)]]
    (upverse to from)
    (consume from)
    {:stop (fn []
             (ca/close! to)
             (ca/close! from)
             (println "engine is stopped"))
     :process (partial produce to)}))
```

this way you can just do `(start-engine)` and use it to process word sequences:

## REPL time

```
boot.user=> (require '[pipeline])

boot.user=> (def engine (pipeline/start-engine))
#'boot.user/engine
```

### running with it

```
boot.user=> ((engine :process) ["apple" "banana" "carrot"])

your word is: TORRAC
your word is: ANANAB
your word is: ELPPA

boot.user=> ((engine :process) ["do" "what" "makes" "sense"])

your word is: OD
your word is: SEKAM
your word is: ESNES
your word is: TAHW
```

### stopping it

```
boot.user=> ((:stop engine))
engine is stopped

;; engine would not process anymore
boot.user=> ((engine :process) ["apple" "banana" "carrot"])
nil
```

## State Management

Depending on how you intend to use this pipeline, a state management framework like Component might not be needed at all: no need to add anything "just in case", starting and stopping the pipeline in this case is a matter of calling two functions.

However in case this pipeline is used within a larger app with more states you could definitely benefit from a state management library.

I am [not a fan of Component](https://github.com/tolitius/mount/blob/master/doc/differences-from-component.md#differences-from-component) primarily because it requires a full app buyin (which makes it a *framework*), but I do respect other people using it.

### mount

I would recommend to either not use anything specific in case the app is small: you, for example could compose this pipeline with other pipelines / logic and kick it off from `-main`, but if the app is any bigger and has more unrelated states, here is all you need to do to add [mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount) to it:

```
(defstate engine :start (start-engine)
                 :stop ((:stop engine)))
```

#### starting pipeline

```
boot.user=> (mount/start)
{:started ["#'pipeline/engine"]}
```

#### running with it

```
boot.user=> ((engine :process) ["do" "what" "makes" "sense"])

your word is: OD
your word is: SEKAM
your word is: ESNES
your word is: TAHW
```

#### stopping it

```
boot.user=> (mount/stop)
engine is stopped
{:stopped ["#'pipeline/engine"]}
```

---

Here is a [gist with a full example](https://gist.github.com/tolitius/248fb389f65aeef0ef5e575ac0af5fcd) that includes `build.boot`.

You can just download and play with it via `boot repl`

---

## [EDIT]: to answer the comments

In case you are already hooked on Component, this should get you started:

```
(defrecord WordEngine []
  component/Lifecycle

  (start [component]
    (merge component (start-engine)))

  (stop [component]
    ((:stop component))
    (assoc component :process nil :stop nil)))
```

This, on start, would create a `WordEngine` object that would have a `:process` *method*.

You won't be able to call it as you would a normal Clojure function: i.e. from REPL or any namespace just by `:require`ing it, unless you pass a reference to the whole system around which is not recommended.

So in order to call it, this `WordEngine` would need to be plugged into a Component system, and injected into yet another Component which can then destructure the `:process` function and call it.

Comment: Great example of Mount+Async, which, like you say would probably be preferred for smaller use cases. I actually spent a lot of time with both Component *and* Mount before settling on Component for *this* job, namely because I like what the "framework" provides. For me, this is a piece of a larger system that has already "bought in" to Component, and I'd really love to get an example running for component, although I'll dog ear this since it's a great Mount example! (plus, i love that it's `boot`, i'm planning to switch eventually :)

Comment: what I mean by smaller cases is use nothing at all: just Clojure. Mount is currently used in many large apps very successfully. In fact I just heard a week ago from one of the companies who switched their 20K LOC app from Component to Mount and can't be happier. I added a sample Component example to the answer.

Comment: I appreciate all your time in advocating and supporting `Mount`! Compared to what I understand about stuart sierra, and weavejester (james?)'s take on Component, I would suspect their approach to this toy problem would look more generic, ie just a `channel` or `pipeline` component (complete with `boundary`s?), instead of a `WordEngine`, and remedy some of the (otherwise valid) critiques you levy against it. Still, there are certainly tradeoffs, and you're convincing me to give `mount` more of a chance, so thanks for that! I appreciate it tolitius!

Comment: sure, Josh, very welcome :) making it a `channel` / `pipeline` with "`boundary`" protocols has nothing to do with (an orthogonal choice to) component or mount though, since it's just a design choice that can be implemented in both. In _your example/use case_ thought this level of abstraction would be an overkill (my opinion).